# Regex to find content, then backtrack to initial HTML tag

Tags: html, regex, editor

I'm trying to use regex to match a string that starts with a `<p>` tag and has `some specific content`. Then, I want to replace everything from that specific paragraph tag to the end of the page.

I've tried using the expression `<p.*?some content.*</html>`, but it grabs the first `<p>` tag it sees, then follows through all the way to the end. I want it to only recognize the paragraph tag immediately preceding the content, allowing for other content and tags between the paragraph tag and the content.

How can I get to `some specific content` with the regex, then backtrack to the first paragraph tag it sees before the content, and then select everything from there to the end?

If it helps, I'm using EditPad Pro's "Search & Replace" function (although this could apply to anything that uses regex).

Comment: You should not use regex to parse HTML !!!

Comment: As stated, RegEx cannot properly represent all HTML. It might fail to properly parse yours.

Comment: I'm just trying to use Search & Replace across multiple HTML pages, with some basic rules to add flexibility while staying accurate. Is there a better tool for doing this?

Comment: Are you using a back-end program like PHP to perform the search/replace? or just a text editor?

Comment: I'm currently using EditPad Pro. I also have Microsoft FrontPage available (sigh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple input use regex

`<p[^<]*some content.*<\/html>`

but safer would be to use regex

`<p(?:[^<]*|<(?!p\b))*some content.*<\/html>`

Comment: Can this match carriage returns and line feeds? or the CR & LF's break the pattern match altogether? Because I remembered using regex in PHP, and I have to remove the \r\n's first before the match to successfully match to the end of the html code.

Comment: @DexterHuinda - you have to use option `/s` for that, so the code should be `$pattern = '/<p(?:[^<]*|<(?!p\b))*some content.*<\/html>/s'; echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);`

Comment: Okay, so the 's' does the trick, what does it mean btw? I know g = global, i = case insensitive, so what does s mean?

Comment: @DexterHuinda - `/s` enables "single-line mode". In this mode, the dot matches newlines. Learn more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: Nice. I just wanted to know about the `s` thing. I have not encountered that before. Thanks for the quick info.

Answer (score 0):

To start, this is Java code, but it can be easily adapted to other regex engines / programming languages, I suppose.

So from what I understand, you want a situation where a given input has a part that starts with `<p>` and immediately followed by some target content/phrase. You then want to replace everything following the initial `<p>` tag with some other content?

If that is correct, you could do something like this:

```
String input; // holds your input text/html
String targetPhrase = "some specific content"; // some target content/phrase
String replacement; // holds the replacement value

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<p[^>]*>(" + targetPhrase + ".*)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
m.replaceFirst(replacement);
```

Of course, as mentioned in above comments, you really don't want to be using regex for HTML.

Alternatively, if you know that if the `<p>` tag is just that, with no properties or anything, you could try a substring instead.

So for example, if you're looking for `"<p>some specific content"`, you could try something like:

```
String input; // your input text/html
String replacement; // the replacement value(s)

int index = input.indexOf("<p>some specific content");
if (index > -1) {
    String output = input.substring(0, index);
    output += "<p>" + replacement;

    // now output holds your modified text/html
}
```

Comment: The <p> tag does have properties, which may be slightly different among different pages.

I'm going to try the first one, and if successful, accept your answer.

I will also Google alternative tools other than regex, as apparently  the consensus is that HTML and regex are not great friends.

Comment: The first code, `<p[^>]*>` should snag all the properties. Just make sure to have your tool make it case insensitive.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to translate your Java code into pure regex, or whatever this Search & Replace function on EditPad Pro is taking. 

I tried <p[^>]*>some specific content.*</html> but that didn't work. I am new to regex (obviously), so I have no idea what I'm doing. I tried reading the EditPad Pro manual, which is comprehensive but confusing for a beginner like myself. 

Although regex and HTML don't work well together, it may be useful to note that this is a one-time-only operation of find & replace, and nothing will need to be done on the fly.

Comment: You need to make sure your regex engine is case insensitive and accepts multiline inputs. Then I strongly suggest [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for at least learning the regex basics.